# Programar botón buscar en IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, html5, indexeddb

Estoy programando un script que contiene un botón; el cual desarrolle una función que busca por número de identificación un registro (objeto).

Esta es la función:

```
function buscarobjeto(){ 
    var transaction = db.transaction(["gente"],"readonly"); 
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("gente"); 
    var ob = objectStore.get(numero); 
    bd.onsuccess = function(e) { }
```

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Base de Datos con JavaScript</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var bd;
            function iniciar(){
    
                MostrarDatos=document.getElementById("MostrarDatos");
                boton=document.getElementById("grabar");
                boton.addEventListener("click",agregarobjeto, false);

                boton=document.getElementById("buscar");
                boton.addEventListener("click",buscarobjeto, false);
                var solicitud=indexedDB.open("sistemas");
    
                solicitud.onsuccess=function(e){
                    bd=e.target.result;
                }
    
                solicitud.onupgradeneeded=function(e){
                    bd=e.target.result;
                    bd.createObjectStore("gente", {keyPath: "nombre"});
                } 
            }

            function agregarobjeto(){
                var nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
                var apellido=document.getElementById("apellido").value;
                var identificacion=document.getElementById("identificacion").value;
                var numero=document.getElementById("numero").value;
                var facultad=document.getElementById("facultad").value;
                var programa=document.getElementById("programa").value;
                var semestre=document.getElementById("semestre").value;
                var asignatura=document.getElementById("asignatura").value;
                var transaccion=bd.transaction(["gente"], "readwrite");
                var almacen=transaccion.objectStore("gente");
                var agregar=almacen.add({nombre: nombre, apellido: apellido, identificacion: identificacion, numero: numero, facultad: facultad, 
                programa: programa, semestre: semestre, asignatura: asignatura});

                agregar.addEventListener("success", mostrar, false);
                document.getElementById("nombre").value=""
                document.getElementById("apellido").value=""
                document.getElementById("identificacion").value=""
                document.getElementById("numero").value=""
                document.getElementById("facultad").value=""
                document.getElementById("programa").value=""
                document.getElementById("semestre").value=""
                document.getElementById("asignatura").value="" 
            }

            function mostrar(){
                MostrarDatos.innerHTML="";
                var transaccion=bd.transaction(["gente"],"readonly");
                var almacen=transaccion.objectStore("gente");
                var cursor=almacen.openCursor();
                cursor.addEventListener("success", mostrarDatos, false);
            }
            
            function buscarobjeto(){                                                                
                

                }

            window.addEventListener("load", iniciar, false);
            var elements = [];

            function mostrarDatos(e){
                var cursor=e.target.result;
                if(cursor){
                    MostrarDatos.innerHTML+="<div><table border=1></caption><thead>" 
                    + "<tr> <td width=85>" + cursor.value.nombre 
                    + "</td><td width=85>" + cursor.value.apellido 
                    + "</td><td width=85>" + cursor.value.identificacion 
                    + "</td><td width=85>" + cursor.value.numero 
                    + "</td><td width=85>" + cursor.value.facultad 
                    + "</td><td width=85>" + cursor.value.programa 
                    + "</td><td width=85>" + cursor.value.semestre 
                    + "</td><td width=85>" + cursor.value.asignatura 
                    + "</td></tr></thead></table></div>";
                    cursor.continue();
                }
            }
        
                            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>     
        <form name="formulario">
            <div id="contenedor">
                <section id="cajaformulario">    
                    <table border=1>
                        <caption><B>Registro de Estudiantes</B></caption>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Introducir nombre" /></th>
                                    <th><input type="text" id="apellido" placeholder="Introducir apellido" /></th>
                                    <th><input type="text" id="identificacion" placeholder="Introducir tipo identificacion" /> </th>
                                    <th><input type="text" id="numero" placeholder="Introducir # de identificación" /></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    
                                    <th><input type="text" id="facultad" placeholder="Introducir facultad" /></th>
                                    <th><input type="text" id="programa" placeholder="Introducir programa" /></th>
                                    <th><input type="text" id="semestre" placeholder="Introducir semestre" /></th>
                                    <th><input type="text" id="asignatura" placeholder="Introducir asignatura" /></th>      
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan=7><button type="button" name="grabar" id="grabar" value="Grabar">Guardar</button></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan=7><button type="button" name="buscar" id="buscar" value="Buscar">Buscar</button></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                    </table>  
                </section>
            </div>

            <div id="elements">
                <section id="MostrarDatos">
                    <table border=1>
                        <caption><B>Estudiante(s) Registrado(s)</B></caption>
                            <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width=85><B><Center>Nombre</B></td>
                                        <td width=85><B><Center>Apellido</B></td>
                                        <td width=135><B><Center>T de Identificación</B></td>
                                        <td width=135><B><Center>N de dentificacion</B></td>
                                        <td width=85><B><Center>Facultad</B></td>
                                        <td width=85><B><Center>Programa</B></td>
                                        <td width=85><B><Center>Semestre</B></td>
                                        <td width=85><B><Center>Asignatura</B></td>
                                    </tr>
                            </thead>
                        <tbody id="cursor">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="9">No hay elementos a mostrar</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                </section>
            </div>    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?, ¿por qué no funciona?

Comment: Gracias por responder, después de guardar un registro, quiero poder buscarlo y editarlo

Comment: "No funciona" es demasiado vago. Dinos qué quieres conseguir y qué errores obtienes. Necesitas mejorar bastante esta pregunta para que no sea cerrada.

Comment: Si la editas y agregas mas información, un poco mas clara y concreta tal vez se pueda abrir nuevamente. Tenes algún log, o mensaje de error algo como para orientar mas a los que te pueden llegar a ayudar.

Comment: Pues, con las últimas modificaciones parece que podemos reabrirla

Comment: Hola @JaksonMoreno, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Para poder responder tu pregunta necesitamos que aclares qué no está funcionando y cómo debería funcionar tu código.

Comment: El código que les presento, abre una base de datos en IndexedDB, crea un almacén llamado gente y guarda los registros (objetos) que un usuario ingrese.  Después de guardar los registros (objetos), quiero tener un botón que busque un registro y poder actualizar los campos de ese registro.

Comment: @CésarBustíos las modificaciones has sido solo de formato y además han sido revertidas inexplicablemente por Jakson Moreno, la pregunta sigue siendo siendo inválida en este sitio, ya que el código de la función `buscarobjeto` esta vacío y sin más indicación de que es lo que se ha intentado hasta el momento

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz entiendo, retiro mi voto entonces. Acabo de ver el rollback de Jakson

Comment: @JaksonMoreno ya has publicado parte del código del botón en el sitio en inglés [Botón buscar en IndexedDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205216/bot%C3%B3n-buscar-en-indexeddb), porque no completas ese código acá, explicas bastante mejor lo que has intentado hasta el momento, aceptas las sugerencias de modificaciones y nos ayudas a resolver tu problema. Si solo demandas que se te ayude sin esforzarte antes nadie se va a interesar por ayudarte

Comment: Entiendo lo del esfuerzo. Yo estaba trabajando una función para buscar pero no logro que funcione, disculpen por agregarla en el comentario, no se como es lo correcto, la función que tengo es esta, en la que intento buscar por número de identificación un registro (objeto)       function buscarobjeto(){                                                                
                                 var transaction = db.transaction(["gente"],"readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("gente");
    var ob = objectStore.get(numero);
    bd.onsuccess = function(e) {
 
    }

Comment: @JaksonMoreno no lo agregues al comentario, sino mas bien edita tu pregunta. Además indica porque no funciona, en que línea se cae, que error sale, etc

Comment: Gracias, tendré en cuenta lo de editar la pregunta, cuando incluyo la función en el código, realmente no pasa nada, no se cae, no marca ningún error, tampoco busca el registro que intento buscar con el número en el campo número y usando el botón buscar, quisiera saber ¿cómo agregar una captura de mi pantalla?

Comment: @JaksonMoreno, he editado su pregunta, pero considero que (después de leer los comentarios), debería agregar esta información `descrita en los comentarios` a su pregunta. Sigo aún sin entender si `al menos` puede con su código conectarse a la base de datos en indexedDB...

Comment: En tu función la variable `numero` no está definida, ¿puede ser?

Answer (score 1):

**Qué es lo que falla**

La función de búsqueda que se muestra en la pregunta tiene algunos problemas. Vamos a verlos uno por uno:

```
function buscarobjeto(){ 
    var transaction = db.transaction(["gente"],"readonly"); 
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("gente"); 
    var ob = objectStore.get(numero); 
    bd.onsuccess = function(e) { }
}
```

1. La base de datos está en `bd` pero la transacción se hace en `db`.
2. `numero` no es el nombre de una variable, sino el nombre de la columna/índice que quieres buscar y deberías entrecomillarlo (aunque como explico más adelante, podría ser correcto pero hay más cosas que necesitarían cambios aquí).
3. El evento `onsuccess` ocurre en `ob` pero se está escuchando en `bd`.
4. El evento `onsuccess` está vacío, con lo cual, incluso si se encontrara algo, no se está realizando ninguna operación con el resultado.

Pero aún hay más. Incluso si se arreglan los errores indicados arriba, seguiría habiendo problemas por cómo se crea la base de datos:

```
bd.createObjectStore("gente", {keyPath: "nombre"});
```

Se especifica que la clave va a ser "nombre", pero no se indica ningún otro campo como índice (*index*), por lo que no se podrán realizar búsquedas nada más que por "nombre" y no por ningún otro campo.

---

**Cómo solucionarlo**

Empieza por añadir un índice en la columna "numero" para poder buscar por ella:

```
var ob = bd.createObjectStore("gente", {keyPath: ["nombre"]});
ob.createIndex("numero", "numero", { unique: false });
```

> **Nota:** Usar el nombre como clave no es una buena idea. Tal y como está definida la tabla, la clave es "nombre" por lo que no se permitirá tener dos registros/personas con el mismo nombre. Lo he dejado de esta manera para modificar el código lo mínimo posible, pero realmente creo que deberías reconsiderar las claves.

Ahora que tienes la columna "numero" como índice, vamos a hacer algunos cambios en la función `buscarobjeto`:

```
function buscarobjeto(){       
    MostrarDatos.innerHTML="";
    var numero = document.getElementById("numero").value;
    var transaction = bd.transaction(["gente"],"readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("gente"); 
    var index = objectStore.index("numero");
    var ob = index.openCursor(numero);
    ob.addEventListener("success", mostrarDatos, false);
}
```

Y de esta manera, se buscarán los registros cuyo número sea idéntico al escrito en el campo "número" del formulario (puede haber más de uno porque el campo no es único cuando se crea).

Los cambios que se han hecho en la función:

- Borramos el `div` con los resultados donde se mostrarán los datos.
- Leemos el campo "número" y lo guardamos en una variable.
- Indicamos que se buscará por el índice "numero" (`var index = objectStore.index("numero");`)
- Abrimos un cursor para atravesar los resultados (de nuevo, puede que esta no sea la manera óptima de hacerlo, pero es para poder reusar el código ya existente).
- Asociamos el evento `onsuccess` con `mostrarDatos` para que se muestren los resultados de la misma manera que cuando se inserta un registro.